# android: exception when using MediaPlayer.SelectTrack on internal subtitle

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, subtitle

I get  `timed_text_track_id` using `mediaplayer.trackinfo` and use it to change internal subtitle of a given video stream as `mediaplayer.selecttrack(timed_text_track_id)`.

When i use SelectTrack to change internal dvbsub subtitle track in this videoview i get an error as follows:

```
12-27 18:53:50.905: E/MediaPlayer(15688): internal/external state mismatch corrected
12-27 18:53:50.915: E/MediaPlayer(15688): error (100, 0)
12-27 18:53:51.385: E/AndroidRuntime(15688): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 18:53:51.385: E/AndroidRuntime(15688): Process: com.example.gent3, PID: 15688
12-27 18:53:51.385: E/AndroidRuntime(15688): java.lang.RuntimeException: failure code: -32
12-27 18:53:51.385: E/AndroidRuntime(15688):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.invoke(MediaPlayer.java:710)
12-27 18:53:51.385: E/AndroidRuntime(15688):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.selectOrDeselectInbandTrack(MediaPlayer.java:3067)
12-27 18:53:51.385: E/AndroidRuntime(15688):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.selectOrDeselectTrack(MediaPlayer.java:3056)
12-27 18:53:51.385: E/AndroidRuntime(15688):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.selectTrack(MediaPlayer.java:3014)
12-27 18:53:51.385: E/AndroidRuntime(15688):    at com.example.gent3.TV$18.onClick(TV.java:1640)
12-27 18:53:51.385: E/AndroidRuntime(15688):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
```

when i use same code to select an audio track on the same video stream there is no error and the audio track is changed.